# How to serialize many-to-many-to-one relationship in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a many-to-many-to-one relationship I would like to represent in DRF. I can get the relevant fields using a `SerializerMethodField` but it feels like there should be a cleaner way.

Setup:

```py
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class Textbook(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class ETextBook(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    textbook = models.OneToOneField(Textbook, on_delete=CASCADE, related_name="etextbook")

class Author(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    textbooks = models.ManyToManyField(Textbook, related_name="authors")

class ETextBookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ETextBook
        fields = "__all__"
```

Ugly working solution:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ("id", "textbooks", "etextbooks")

    etextbooks = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_etextbooks(self, obj):
        etextbooks = ETextbook.objects.filter(textbook__authors=obj)
        return ETextBookSerializer(etextbooks, many=True).data
```

But what I'd really like to do is:

```py
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ("id", "textbooks", "etextbooks")

    etextbooks = ETextBookSerializer(source="textbooks.etextbook", many=True)
```

but this raises a:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 446, in get_attribute
    return get_attribute(instance, self.source_attrs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 96, in get_attribute
    instance = getattr(instance, attr)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'etextbook'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 56, in retrieve
    return Response(serializer.data)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 555, in data
    ret = super().data
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 253, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 509, in to_representation
    attribute = field.get_attribute(instance)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/scottgigante/envs/django/lib/python3.11/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 479, in get_attribute
    raise type(exc)(msg)
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `etextbooks` on serializer `AuthorSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Author` instance.
Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'etextbook'.
```

Comment: You know that `"textbooks.etextbook"` will have to be filtered for that which belongs to `Author`. Which makes me ask, why is that which works ugly?

Comment: EtextBook is one-to-one with Textbook; the authorship here is implied to carry over from any textbook authored by the author to its EtextBook, if one exists.